# What is wrong with this program that passes an int to puts()?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{
    int value = 3;
    puts(value);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run it, it says "*project_name* has stopped working"

Comment: And you don't get a compiler warning for that code?

Comment: Please read the docs (man pages or online) for the functions you're calling.

Answer (score 3):

`puts` expects an argument of `const char*`. You provide an argument of type `int`. Hence your program crashes.

Instead use `printf`:

```
printf("%d\n",value);
```

Comment: Adding a `\n` would be better, as `puts` would, also flushes the buffer.

Comment: @YuHao , Yeah.Good Point.